# Limitations of Force.com Site Guest User?

Tags: force.com, force.com-sites

What are the limitations of the Force.com Site Guest User?

I tried searching for it but couldn't find full limitations of the Guest User. I did find some limitations, such as:

> 1 guest user license per site and you can create up to (max) 25 sites

But I want all the limitations with unlimited edition.

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head the first one is that a guest user cannot edit a standard object, but they can read/create one (screenshot from Opportunity object):

[image]

I'm not aware of a way around this such, without creating either using a custom object (which they can edit) or a child object that update the parent/target.

I'm sure there are more.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have access to users, accounts, contacts, etc.  You can access them only by creating wrapper classes for those objects.  Given that you're already coding pages, it's not that much more work.

If any custom object has a master detail relationship to a standard object that the user can't see, the can't see the child object either.

There's no chatter...you might want something to post internally when the site guest user does something, but you can't.

No reporting or dashboarding.

The guest user can own records, but can't be part of sharing rules.

The guest user doesn't have any error details on their error page.  If you have an apex runtime exception, you'll get an auth error instead of the actual error in the UI.

Sites has its own limitations (page views, bandwidth, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Please see below.

- Guest user licenses are required for force.com sites.
- List item EE/UE orgs are allowed to create up to 25 sites hence the 25 guest user licenses.
- Each site has a special user with a user type called guest user type
  Guest users have no password, no role and have no API access on their
  profile.
- You can't login or do client side api call (only within
  apex code).
- If you need API access for guest users, the  "Guest API
  Access Enabled" org permission needs to be enabled.
- There is no session for guest browsing Each guest user (site) has a unique
  profile (public access settings)
- These profiles are associated to guest user licenses which give the ability to read/create on standard objects and full CRUD on custom objects.
  However, by default no CRUD is given.
- Admins needs to enable the right level of access based on
  their flow.

Hope [this](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000006778&language=en_US) helps.